# command composer Install give error failed to extract

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I'm using ubuntu server & trying to run `composer install` command in my Laravel project. But it give error

```
Failed to extract brick/math: (2) '/usr/bin/unzip' -qq '/var/www/html/xtendanceweb/vendor/composer/tmp-9f6f68323bcc502e257e735e3f7dcac8' -d '/var/www/html/xtendanceweb/vendor/composer/8fe377e7'

sh: 1: Cannot fork

    The archive may contain identical file names with different capitalization (which fails on case insensitive filesystems)
    Unzip with unzip command failed, falling back to ZipArchive class
```

I don't know why this is happening, any help would be helpful for me

Comment: Did you try to clear composer cache? `composer clearcache`

Comment: related: [laravel "failed to extract / bad CRC" errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65203694/laravel-homestead-random-failed-to-extract-errors)

Comment: related: [php composer install error: Unzip with unzip command failed, falling back to ZipArchive class](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/failed-to-install-with-composer?page=1&replyId=513099) , [Failed to extract using '/usr/bin/unzip'](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/10379)

Comment: related: [composer ZIP uncompress errors when installing/updating dependencies](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5982)

Answer (score -1):

Do `composer clearcache` first, then try to run the command again