# How to solve Failed to extract laravel-frontend-presets/material-dashboard: (1) "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\unzip.EXE"

Tags: laravel

I am trying to integrate integrate Material Dashboard 2 by Creative Tim in my Laravel web application but it says :

[image]

I tried installing the by Archive also, but still, the same error. This is the instruction that I followed from https://github.com/laravel-frontend-presets/material-dashboard

[image]

Comment: It seems to be a similar error: [composer/composer #10379](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/10379) - GitHub Issue - Have you tried deleting the vendor folder and the lock file, then starting the installation again?

Comment: Related to a previously asked question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71215846/15167500 - They suggest using the `composer clearcache` [composer/composer #5982](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5982#issuecomment-420920343) command here in several places. - An alternative-looking suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65310533/15167500